# how to update label with a global variable

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a score system that just shows the score on an updating label - the score info (score1) is set in another function, and I cant find a solution. you can disregard the code below as its just my desperate try and my lack of understanding

```
import tkinter
import random

score1 = 0
def example 
    global score1
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    if (n == 3)
        score1 = score1 + 1

label = tkinter.Label(root, text=score1, font = ('', 30))
label.pack()

def update():
    global score1
    scoreIS = score1
    label['text'] = scoreIS

root.after(100, update)
update()

root.mainloop()
```

edit: score1 =0 was added but still doesn't work, the labels shows up but doesn't change

Comment: Put `label.config(text=score1)` at the end of the `example` function

Comment: call `root.after(100, update)` inside the `update` function. Also, `def example ` should be `def example(): ` and I believe `scoreIS = score1` should be `scoreIS= example()`. Also, note that example function should return `score1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the global variable at the module level before you can override it in a function. Adjust your code to the following:

```
import tkinter
import random

score1 = 0

def example 
    global score1
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    if (n == 3)
        score1 = score1 + 1

label = tkinter.Label(root, text=score1, font = ('', 30))
label.pack()

def update():
    global score1
    label['text'] = score1

root.after(100, update)
update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is very inefficient as the method `update` will always run. It is simpler to just put `label["text"] = scrore1` at the end of all function that change the value of `score1`. Also it will update only 10 times a second. What is the value of score needs to change more frequently?

Answer (score 0):

To update the label's text you have to use the `.config` method like this: `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=...)`

Your code with the label being configure with the new text:

```py
import tkinter
import random

def example():
    global score1
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    if (n == 3):
        score1 += 1
    label.config(text=score1)

label = tkinter.Label(root, text=score1, font = ('', 30))
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Each time you call `example` the text inside the label will be updated.

Comment: Yes, that is way better now thanks. I just copied OP's code and didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

# setup UI
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="0", font=('', 30))
label.pack()


def set_score(value):
    '''call this function only when the score is changed'''
    #global root # already global
    #global label #  already global
    label['text'] = str(value)
    #root.update() #don't need root.update() if you have root.mainloop()


set_score(100)  # any where you need to change score value
root.mainloop()
```

In my opinion, create a pure function to update score when you need it.

Comment: You don't need `root.update()` if you have `root.mainloop()`. Also the variable `label` is already global so you don't even need the `global label`.